# Why UIView is relayout in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, autolayout

My Manager UIViewController is shown in attached figure. It has Draw Chart UIView and Draw Chart UIView has a small UIView inside.
Draw Chart UIView's size is smaller than superview.

Draw Chart UIView has layout constraints as shown in the second figure.
Small UIView has no constraints. It's locations are changed where user tap on the Draw Chart UIView. So no constraints.
When I load Draw Chart UIView, it is fine and layout is same as in constraints.

The problem is when I load small UIView or keyboard appeared, Draw Chart UIView is relayout and height is taller. So DONE button is pushed to the lower position.
How to prevent, even small UIView is loaded/keyboard appeared Draw Chart UIView's size and layout are not changed. Can it be done in auto layout and constraints?
I can't find where to fix it?
Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try putting the main view in scroll view and the draw chart view in another scroll view and then change the y position of the scroll view as per your requirement and also when the keyboard pops up.

Comment: Let me test. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks it works. Can you please answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the main view in scroll view and the draw chart view in another scroll view and then change the y position of the scroll view as per your requirement and also when the keyboard pops up.